# tomcat crashes when buffered image is created via xvfb

Tags: java, tomcat, xvfb

When my webapp servlet calls xvfb to create a buffered image this error arises and tomcat just crashes.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: undefined symbol: Xutf8TextListToTextProperty
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `-Djava.awt.headless=true` yet?

Comment: Where do I have to put that? In the tomcat catalina.sh maybe?

Comment: You put it wherever JVM options go.

Comment: Paste the output of `java -version`.

Comment: java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.8.0.el5_9-i386)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: I have found that the icedtea JDKs are nothing but trouble.  It would not surprise me if it did not work with the headless flag OR xvfb!  Do yourself a favor and get a less "free" version of Java such as OpenJDK, or even better the real Oracle JDK.

Comment: I downgraded to jdk 1.6. Now I do get another exception. I've posted it into another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573581/xvfb-image-buffering-provokes-java-awt-headless-exception)

Comment: Now I upgraded to a oracle java 1.7 jdk and I got this very same error again. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the code from your other question, I see that you are using a `Frame` which will not work in headless mode.  (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html)  What have you done to configure XVFB?  What platform are you trying to run it on?

Comment: I noticed that, too. I removed the -Djava.awt.headless=true statement and that error message popped up again. Currently I'm running a tomcat 5 on this java 1.7 jdk from oracle. The Linux is a RHEL 5 32 bit. I do have a tomcat 6 and a tomcat 7 also installed for debug purposes. This occurs also in tomcat 6 with jdk 6 and 7. So it is something unrelated to the jdk and the version of tomcat. Any ideas?

Comment: I managed to reproduce the system on a newer debian powered machine. I had to change some code in the class files managing the imageIO though. Somehow url is easier to procedure than an actual file input. It seams that rhel 5 is just too outdated to host a java 1.7, tomcat application. Unfortunately there was no real solution to this error message. I'll have to update the server with a newer linux distribution. rhel 5 seams to be from 2002. Thank you Bailey!